rushjs monorepo ; Root directory quick installation dependencies
I want to execute rush add to install dependencies for subprojects in the root directory, just like pnpm --filter, or enhance the rush add --to function. Is there a reliable implementation?
And I use fnm or vnm to manage the node version, nvmrc cannot take effect on the entire rush directory
